# Изменить цвет ячейки таблицы с записью текущего цвета в localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, localstorage

Задача: есть таблица из нескольких ячеек (например - 4).
Каждая ячейка имеет один и тот-же цвет фона (например - красный).
Нужно, что-бы при при щелчке по ячейке, цвет менялся на другой (например - зелёный), и данные о цвете каждой ячейке хранились в localstorage, что-бы после обновления/повторного открывания страницы таблица запоминала своё состояние.

Comment: И что у вас не получается? Что уже пробовали?

Comment: Чесно: не смог свести всё в рабочий вариант.

Comment: Получаю ошибку
file.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at init (file.js:10)
    at file.js:36
init @ file.js:10
(anonymous) @

Answer (score 0):

Для упорядоченных ячеек

```
const COLOR_1 = 'red';
const COLOR_2 = 'green';

const init = () => {
  // получаем массив с классами из localStorage
  const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('classes'));

  // эта проверка нужна, что бы сделать красным цветом ячейки, индексов которых нет в localStorage
  // т.е, если в localStorage данные для 4 ячеек а мы в разметку добавили ещё 4
  if (data.length < tds.length)
    // возвращаем новый массив, который состоит из массива data и нового массива, длинна которого равна недостающему количеству элементов
    // функция createArray расположена ниже
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax
    return [...data, ...createArray(tds.length - data.length)]
  else if (!data)
    return new Array(len).fill(COLOR_1)

  return data
}

// просто заполняем новый массив строками 'red' len-раз
const createArray = len => new Array(len).fill(COLOR_1)

// если элемент, по которому произошел клик, является ячейкой, меняем его цвет на зеленый
const changeColor = e => e.target.tagName == 'TD' ? e.target.classList.toggle(COLOR_2) : null


const setLocalStorage = () => {
  // получаем классы для каждой ячейки и записываем их в массив
  classes = [...tds].map(td => td.className)
  // запихиваем этот массив в localStorage
  localStorage.setItem('classes', JSON.stringify(classes))
}

const tds = document.querySelectorAll('td')
let classes = init();

// цвета для ячеек при загрузке страницы
tds.forEach((td, i) => td.className = classes[i])

const table = document.querySelector('table')

table.addEventListener('click', e => {
  changeColor(e)
  setLocalStorage()
})
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" width="100%" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```